# Showing mobile friendly web page without having to zoom in

Tags: html, asp.net, mobile-website

I'm trying to create a mobile friendly web page using the code below. When I view it over a HTC desire I have to zoom in to see the correct size. How can I get it to display normally without having to zoom in?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MobileSite._Default" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<head runat="server">
    <title>My Mobile Site</title>
</head>
<body style="width: 480px">
    <form id="form" runat="server">
    <div>    
        Test<br />
        Test<br />
        Test
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if the HTC supports the viewport meta tag the same way the iPhone does, but you can try:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width = 320" />
```

(or some other width) or:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK only webkit based browsers respect viewport.
If you don't set size for table and div and keep mobile doctype most of the browsers should fit it properly to the screen